# Adding Java final keyword to working method that builds instances inside a loop

Tags: java, for-loop, final

Take the following POJOs:

```
public class Widget {
    private String fizz;
    private Long buzz;
    private List<Fidget> collaborators;

   // Constructor, getters & setters
}

public class Fidget {
    private String fizz;
    private String foo;

    // Constructor, getters & setters
}
```

And the following (working) method:

```
public void compriseWidgets(List<Fidget> fidgetList) {
    List<Widget> widgets = new ArrayList<Widget>();
    Widget currentWidget = null;

    for (Fidget fidget : fidgetList) {
        if (currentWidget == null || 
                !currentWidget.getFizz().equals(fidget.getFizz())) {

            currentWidget = new Widget();
            widgets.add(currentWidget);
            currentWidget.setFizz(fidget.getFizz());
            currentWidget.setBuzz(fidget.getFoo().length());
        }

        currentWidget.getCollaborators().add(fidget);
    }

    return widgets;
}
```

Here we want to return a `List<Widget>` and populate that list only:

1. From the first `Fidget` in the input list (hence `currentWidget == null`); and
2. If the `Fidget` and `currentWidget` have the same `fizz` value

Furthermore, we want to keep appending `collaborators` to the `currentWidget` regardless of whether the fizzes match or not.

#### My problem

A new code style guideline is requiring that we declare **ALL** variables with `final`...meaning I need to get the above code refactored to look like so:

```
public void compriseWidgets(final List<Fidget> fidgetList) {
    final List<Widget> widgets = new ArrayList<Widget>();
    final Widget currentWidget = null;

    for (final Fidget fidget : fidgetList) {
        ...
    }

    return widgets;
}
```

Because it requires both the creation of a new `Widget` *inside* the loop, but an external (outside the loop) reference to a `Widget` that we can add `collaborators` to, I'm at a total loss for how to rewrite this with `final`. Any ideas? Also, please note, this is nothing that I can "push back" on, I just need to figure it out and get it working with the new coding standard.

Comment: Are you *sure*? I have sometimes seen a style guideline that all *method parameters* be declared `final`, but never that all variables whatever be `final`.  Whatever problem a guideline of the latter kind is intended to solve, the resulting workarounds are likely to be a lot worse.

Comment: For example, you can comply with the letter of the guideline by declaring local variables as collections, arrays, or other containers where you need mutable data.  Let the containers be `final`, and mutate the contents all you like.  Is that better than using non-`final` variables where it makes sense to do so?  By no means.

Comment: Also what is the point of your `if` statement? `currentWidget` is always null so only the first condition of the OR gets evaluated always.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I agree with you, but **yes**, I am sure. The whole team has already pushed back on this, its just the lay of the current land. :-/

Comment: @NicholasK `currentWidget` is only null going into the first iteration of the for-loop. Since its null during this first iteration, the `if`-statement executes and instantiates `currentWidget`. From that point on, regardless of how many `Fidgets` are in the `fidgetList`, and regardless of whether or not the `if`-statement will execute again or not (based on the `fizz` strings matching), `currentWidget` will continue to be non-null. Its confusing, I know. :-/

Comment: Btw, how is the compriseWidgets method working? Its method signature returns void, but the method body returns List<Widget>. Also, about the logic in the loop... it's taking a list of List<Fidget>, and then for each Fidget object, it creates a new Widget object with just a single Fidget in its list?

Comment: Time to look for a new employer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment, you could convert your example code more or less mechanically, like so:

```
public List<Widget> compriseWidgets(final List<Fidget> fidgetList) {
    final List<Widget> widgets = new ArrayList<Widget>();
    final Widget[] currentWidget = new Widget[] {null};

    for (final Fidget fidget : fidgetList) {
        if (currentWidget[0] == null || 
                !currentWidget[0].getFizz().equals(fidget.getFizz())) {

            currentWidget[0] = new Widget();
            widgets.add(currentWidget);
            currentWidget.setFizz(fidget.getFizz());
            currentWidget.setBuzz(fidget.getFoo().length());
        }

        currentWidget.getCollaborators().add(fidget);
    }

    return widgets;
}
```

Many variables can be made `final` without any particular impact, including the lists of Fidgets and Widgets, and the loop variable in the enhanced `for` loop.  The only other variable in the original method was `currentWidget`, which the implementation modifies.  This can be replaced with a (`final`) array of length 1, whose zeroth element can then be used as a drop-in replacement for the original variable.

A more troublesome requirement along the same lines would be that you may not use assignment statements (initializers in variable declarations not being considered "assignments").  This is pushing toward a more functional style of programming, which I suppose may be the intent of your new guideline.  You might, then, approach it something like this:

```
public List<Widget> compriseWidgets(final List<Fidget> fidgetList) {
    final List<Widget> widgets = new ArrayList<Widget>();
    final ListIterator<Fidget> fidgets = fidgetList.listIterator();

    while (addWidget(widgets, fidgets)) { /* empty */ }

    return widgets;
}    

private boolean addWidget(final List<Widget> widgets, final ListIterator<Fidget> fidgets) {
    if (fidgets.hasNext()) {
        final Fidget firstFidget = fidgets.next();
        final Widget currentWidget = new Widget();

        widgets.add(currentWidget);
        currentWidget.setFizz(firstFidget.getFizz());
        currentWidget.setBuzz(firstFidget.getFoo().length());
        currentWidget.getCollaborators().add(firstFidget);

        while (fidgets.hasNext()) {
            final nextFidget = fidgets.next();

            if (currentWidget.getFizz().equals(nextFidget.getFizz())) {
                currentWidget.getCollaborators().add(nextFidget);
            } else {
                fidgets.previous();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is pretty much the same trick, just a little less obvious.  The mutable state is hidden in the call stack (each invocation of `addWidget()` stands in for a mutation of the original method's `currentWidget()`) and in a container object, this time a `ListIterator`.

One could go further in the functional programming direction.  In general, for example, you could look toward Stream-based approaches, though I don't think that works out completely cleanly in this particular case.  More general functional programming does not have the constraints that apply to Streams, however.

Answer (score 0):

The Builder design pattern is a great way to build immutable objects.
Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15461337/4245294

What I love about this version of this design pattern is how it gives you the perfect spot for validation rules **before** object creation.

Example applied to this problem:

```
public class Widget {
    private final String fizz;
    private final Long buzz;
    private final List<Fidget> collaborators;

    private Widget(Builder builder) {
        this.fizz = builder.fizz;
        this.buzz = builder.buzz;
        this.collaborators = builder.collaborators;
    }

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private String fizz;
        private Long buzz;
        private List<Fidget> collaborators = new ArrayList<>();

        public Builder addFizz(String fizz) {
            this.fizz = fizz;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder addBuzz(Long buzz) {
            this.buzz = buzz;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder addCollaborators(List<Fidget> fidgets) {
            collaborators.addAll(fidgets);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder addCollaborator(Fidget fidget) {
            collaborators.add(fidget);
            return this;
        }

        private void validate() throws InvalidArgumentException{
            ArrayList<String> invalidArguments = new ArrayList<>();
            boolean failedValidation = false;
            if (collaborators.isEmpty()) {
                invalidArguments.add("collaborators");
                failedValidation = true;
            }
            if (this.fizz == null) {
                invalidArguments.add("fizz");
                failedValidation = true;
            }
            if (this.buzz == null) {
                invalidArguments.add("buzz");
                failedValidation = true;
            }
            if (failedValidation) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException(invalidArguments.toArray(new String[0]));
            }
        }

        public Widget build() {
            validate();
            return new Widget(this);
        }
    }
}
```

And you create a valid Widget object like so:

```
Widget widget = Widget.builder().addFizz("test").addBuzz(999).addCollaborators(fidgets).build();
```

Your `compriseWidget` method has problems that I mentioned in a comment to the Question, otherwise I would provide an example for that as well.

Comment: Thanks @LXXIII I will check it out. In the meantime do you mind moving this to a comment, or adding code to make this a full answer?